# formatting issue with the hash character

Tags: support, markdown-rendering

I have found an issue with the hash (`#`) character.

> this is a quote, sometimes quotes contain numbers and hashes - typically from MySQL error reports by uses.

Sometimes I read quotes that have been made using a hash as a copy/paste of an error such as:

> ## 124335 error - the MySQL query caused an error as rows are too large.

This is actually `#124335` but the hash makes the whole quote a header, as the user has just copy/pasted this in . You can see this in the edits to the question

[MySQL row size error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232550/mysql-row-size-error)

i) Can SO Meta fix this issue or is there a way to workaround the `#` cahracter causing the whole row to header when in a quote, as this is almost certainly unintended when in this format. ?

Comment: Voted to close because of a simple fix available with already existing markdown facilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use backslash to escape

> #124335 erro - the MySQL query caused an error as rows are too large.

>\#124335 erro - the MySQL query caused an error as rows are too large

Answer (score 2):

#124335 erro - the MySQL query caused an error as rows are too large.

```
\#124335 erro - the MySQL query caused an error as rows are too large.
```

See, you must escape it if you want to suppress its special meaning in markdown.

Answer (score 2):

You can just escape the hash with a backslash character.

For instance:

## This is a hash that's unescaped.

#This is a hash that is escaped.